# How to tell if a UIButton has an image set in XCUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

I'm facing an issue where I need to determine if a UIButton that functions as a link has an image in its imageView using just XCUI properties. I have tried looking at the button itself as well as going through the button's hierarchy

Here's a few things that I've tried:

> accessing the accessibilityValue by way of `po button.accessibilityValue`
> it was nil which makes sense since I didn't set one and since the button in this context doesn't have a value associated with it inherently like a slider or textField might have, but after reading this somewhere I just had to try it just in case.

> accessing the button's children by way of `po button.children`. The result of this was `0 elements`, which makes me think that UIButton's subviews must be private in XCUI..

> Lastly, when I do `po XCUIApplication()` or `po XCUIApplication().buttons` in the console in Xcode the button's subviews are not listed, the button portion of the hierarchy doesn't go any deeper than just the button itself just stops at the UIButton level.

If anyone has any ideas or tips about how this could be achieved I'd be very grateful! Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you provide...
* What code you are using to print the accessibilityValue?
* What code did you use to attempt to access the button's children?
* Could you provide how you are adding the image to the button?
* What happens when you print XCUIApplication.buttons?
* Any prints that you got, that weren't the values you wanted, could you provide them incase they have clues for someone to answer your question?

Thank you

Comment: This is not a suitable use of UI testing. You could use snapshot testing or you could use unit testing.